# How to create multiple many-to-many relationships in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, sql, database, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I read this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60832540/ef-core-multiple-many-to-many-relationships-between-the-same-entities). The author adds in one of the comments saying:

> ... the easiest thing would be to add a PK to the UserSeries table.
> Btw, keep in mind that with the "discriminator" approach, you will
> have a "denormalized" model
> (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) which in the DB world
> is something not desired. Think that if you have some properties that
> are exclusive of the "Fav" relationship (for example, a column rating
> saying how much you liked the series) and some other properties that
> are exclusive of the "Watchlist" relationship (for example, a date you
> would like to watch it), then you will have a lot of null depending on
> the type of the row: fav rows will have null on the date column,
> whereas watchlisted rows will have null on the fav column. That being
> said, that approach however is many times being chosen because it's
> really simple to make queries when all the data is in a single table.

In my case I have `Book` and `Person` entity classes:

```
public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string? Subtitle { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PersonBook> Authors { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PersonBook> Reviewers { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PersonBook> Translators { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PersonBook> BooksAuthored { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PersonBook> BooksReviewed { get; set; }

    public ICollection<PersonBook> BooksTranslated { get; set; }
}

public class PersonBook
{
    [ForeignKey("Book")]
    public int BookID { get; set; }
    
    public Book Book { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Person")]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    public Person Person { get; set; }
}
```

If I go with that first solution to add a discriminator/additional attribute to `PersonBook`:

1. How to add that key while adding entities to the database?
2. How to overcome having a denormalized model?
3. Is there a third solution to this problem besides the 2 @dglozano mentioned in that post?

Comment: Have you checked this https://entityframework.net/many-to-many-relationship

Comment: Yes, that one talks about 1 relationship. I need to create many.